# Overriding header search order for nvcc

Tags: gcc, cuda, thrust, nvcc

I have a CUDA project that uses [Thrust](https://thrust.github.io). Thrust comes with the CUDA Toolkit but I'd like to use a more recent version I've checked out.

I invoke `nvcc` with `-isystem=/path/to/thrust` but the underlying compiler invocation looks like

```
gcc ... "-I/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include"  -isystem "/path/to/thrust"
```

Since gcc searches directories from left to right, that means that the Toolkit's Thrust headers are found first.

Can I override this behavior to find my Thrust checkout first without modifying the CUDA Toolkit or writing a compiler wrapper script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply needed to use `-I` instead of `-isystem`.

I also learned that `-Xcompiler --foo,--bar` allows me to inject other arguments should I need them.